# Defining the Ansible Hosts within the playbook to deploy both ArgoCD and an Application into EKS Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, gitlab, amazon-eks

I have set up a GitLab pipeline to deploy an EKS cluster on AWS, and I'm trying to use Ansible to run a playbook that deploys ArgoCD and an application manifest file stored in the same GitLab repo. However, I'm encountering issues with setting up the hosts and inventory.

Here's the flow and architecture:

1. The build server hosting the runner is in AWS.
2. GitLab and terraform are used to deploy the EKS cluster.
3. After deploying the cluster, I've added a stage in GitLab CI/CD pipeline to set the context in kubeconfig using the command "aws eks update-kubeconfig --region eu-west-1 --name testcluster".
4. This successfully adds and logs in to the cluster with no problems, outputting "Added new context arn:aws:xxxx to /kubeconfig/config."
5. Now, when I try to use Ansible to run the playbook, (As part of the Gitlab pipeline) I encounter the following error:

```
`TASK [Install ArgoCD CLI (argocd)] *********************************************
fatal: [localhost]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Address not available\r\n", "unreachable": true}`
```

```
`PLAY [Install ArgoCD and deploy application] ***********************************
TASK [Install ArgoCD CLI (argocd)] *********************************************
changed: [eks_cluster_1]
 [WARNING]: Consider using 'become', 'become_method', and 'become_user' rather
than running sudo
changed: [localhost]
TASK [Install ArgoCD] ***********************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "kubectl create namespace argocd\n kubectl apply -n argocd -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-cd/stable/manifests/install.yaml", "delta": "0:00:00.909235", "end": "2024-03-11 18:13:48.541536", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 2, "start": "2024-03-11 18:13:47.632301", "stderr": "/usr/local/bin/kubectl: line 1: syntax error: unexpected redirection\n/usr/local/bin/kubectl: line 1: syntax error: unexpected redirection", "stderr_lines": ["/usr/local/bin/kubectl: line 1: syntax error: unexpected redirection", "/usr/local/bin/kubectl: line 1: syntax error: unexpected redirection"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}`
```

Any assistance on how to solve this would be appreciated.

```
**Details on the playbook:**
---
- name: Install ArgoCD and deploy application
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Install ArgoCD CLI (argocd)
      become: yes
      shell: |
        ...

    - name: Install ArgoCD
      become: yes
      shell: |
        ...
 
    - name: Apply ArgoCD application YAML
      become: yes
      shell: ...
```

```
**.gitlab-ci.yml:**
stages:
  - Ansible-Cluster-Configuration

Ansible-Cluster-Configuration:
  stage: Ansible-Cluster-Configuration
  image: williamyeh/ansible:alpine3
  variables:
    KUBECONFIG: /kubeconfig/config
  before_script:
    - apk add --no-cache --upgrade bash  
    - apk add --no-cache curl python3 py3-pip
    - pip3 install --upgrade pip
    - pip3 install awscli
    - curl -LOk "https://dl.k8s.io/release/$(curl -L -s https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"
    - sudo install -o root -g root -m 0755 kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
    - aws eks update-kubeconfig --region eu-west-1 --name testcluster
  script:
    - echo "Deploying ArgoCD and application..."
    - sudo ansible-playbook -i inventory.ini argocd_setup.yml
```

```
**Inventory.ini:**
[all]
eks_cluster_1 ansible_host=localhost ansible_connection=local k8s_auth_host=https://cluster_endpoint
```

Comment: It would be much easier to do all that with Ansible itself. It has ready modules to control [Helm](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/kubernetes/core/helm_module.html), [Terraform](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/terraform_module.html), and a whole [amazon.aws](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/index.html) collection to work with AWS APIs. Moreover, usage of `shell` where there are dedicated modules is considered a bad practice in Ansible.